# Markov property implies that expression ???

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process

My professor has told us that Markov property means that:
Let $\{X_n\}_n$ be a markovian sequence in a countable stte space $X$ then $\{Y_n\} = X_{n+k}$ is also a markovian sequence with the same probability transition matrix $P$ as  $\{X_n\}_n$ ,the same initial disturbution $\pi_0$  and also independent of $X_k,X_{k-1},...,X_0$ .
I found that definition a little bit abstract and I am trying to turn into a formula.
**Is it right to say ?** that the phrase "*is also a markovian sequence with the same probability transition matrix* $P$ as  $\{X_n\}_n$ " can be expressed as

$P[X_{n+k} = b | X_{n+k-1} = a] = P[X_1 = b | X_0 = a] = p(a,b)$ where a,b are two states $\in X$.

Comment: $(Y_n)$ need not be independent of $X_k,,,,X_1,X_0$; for example $\{X,X,X,...\}$ is a Markov chain.

Comment: i think he means independent of their values in terms of **time**: not being dependent on the values of Xn in k and before